# Comparing two results in SQLite for C++?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm trying to write a login function in C++, where the user enters their ID. This ID goes in the query of the SQLite API, and I would like to save the result of the query (what has to be a password) in a variable. And also, the user enters their password, and I would like to compare the entered password and the actual password. The problem is that the actual password, the result of the query is a const unsigned char*, and the entered password is obviously a string. As far as I know, I can't convert a string to const unsigned char, or vice versa. Below, there is the code, that's where I am currently. Is there any way to compare the two passwords?

```
string studentid;
sqlite3* db;
sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
auto rc = sqlite3_open("timetable_newest.sqlite", &db);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
    cerr << "Couldn't open database" << sqlite3_errmsg(db);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
cout << "Enter your student ID: " << endl;
cin >> studentid;
string select = "SELECT password FROM Student_login WHERE id='" + studentid + "'";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, select.c_str(), -1, &stmt, 0);
const unsigned char* password; //has to be const unsigned char*, unless it won't compile
password = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1);
cout << "Enter your password" << endl;
string password_input;
cin >> password_input; //this is where I am now, the solution should start from here
```

Sorry if the question is dumb, or I can't see the obvious thing, I'm quite a beginner for c++. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can compare (string content of) `std::string` with `const char*` (`password == password_input`).

Comment: BTW, better to not store password in DB, but some "hash".

Comment: Your code is subject to SQL injection ! Imagine your user inputs something like `foo' or 1=1 --`

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: As a completely alternative approach, why not let SQLite do the heavy lifting and check if a user exists with the correct (hashed) password? Then you just need to count the number of result rows.

Comment: @Botje Great idea, thanks! It works flawlessly.

Comment: @prapin Thank you for the feedback, fair enough. I took care of it, too.